# Sql запрос по себе отрабатывает отлично, но при вызове в методе executequery вылетает ошибка

Tags: java

> 

'''

```
public List<TransactionReportModel> getAllExpensesId(long clientId, LocalDate 
    dateStart, LocalDate dataFinish) {
            TransactionReportModel transactionReportModel;
        List<TransactionReportModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    
            String query = "select c.name, sum(t.transfer_amount)" +
                    "from category as c" +
                    "join transaction_to_category as ttc on ttc.type_id = c.id" +
                    "join transaction as t on t.id = ttc.transaction_id" +
                    "where c.client_id = ?" +
                    "and t.create_date between ? and ?" +
                    "group by (c.name)";
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setLong(1, clientId);
            ps.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(dateStart));
            ps.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(dataFinish));
    
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);
    
            while (rs.next()) {
                transactionReportModel = new TransactionReportModel();
                transactionReportModel.setName(rs.getString(1));
                transactionReportModel.setAmount(rs.getLong(2));
                list.add(transactionReportModel);
            }
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            throw new CustomException(e);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

'''

Comment: Опечатка при передаче query в executequery, должен быть просто вызов executequery

Comment: Вы можете показать более детальный текст ошибки?  Потому что  сложно  понять смысл  ошибки.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" ru.altalaev.Exception.CustomException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "transaction_to_category")
  Позиция: 61

Comment: поставьте пробелы в конце каждой строки sql запроса

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло